# Modifying a React component with a user script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tampermonkey, userscripts

### Short version

How can I modify a React component with a user script (e.g. code injected by Tampermonkey) without breaking the app when I don't have access to the original source?

### Longer version

Modifying the DOM of a React component directly can break the app because the [reconciliation algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) can get confused by manual DOM changes. Hence, I would like to modify a React component in my user script so React can keep rendering unhindered.

In a simple setup, React discovers components in the global namespace, and we can modify a component easily (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b2d5vLj/4/) for a working example):

```
oldComponent = Component
function Component(props) {
  // modify the props to change the appearance of the component
  return oldComponent(modifiedProps);
}
```

However, the situation is more complex when the application is deployed because the components are typically bundled using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). How would I be able to reproduce the example above in an application whose components have been bundled?

Comment: Interrogate the transpiled object?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, definitely a good option. Are you aware of any documentation for the structure of the transpiled objects?

Comment: Use the same approach used by React Devtools: expose React's debugging hook (I forgot its exact spelling, sorry) in [page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).